# Не удается запарсить xlsx в архив JSON объектов

Tags: javascript, xlsx

вот с чем столкнулся, используя библиотеку xlsx в ноде смогу запарсить документ в архив с объектами. Но так получилось, что сейчас нужно сделать тоже самое только без Ноды... и вот тут у меня затык ( не хочет парсить, такое ощущение, что вообще не видит файл.

Это работающий фрагмент кода.

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
let workbook = XLSX.readFile('users.xlsx', {
    type: "buffer",
    sheetRows: 10000,
});
let sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
let parsedUsersListArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name], {
    blankrows: true,
    defval: null
});
console.log(parsedUsersListArr.length);
```

А вот это не работает :(

```
let book = XLSX.read('users.xlsx', {
    type: "buffer",
    sheetRows: 10000,
});
let sheet_name = book.SheetNames[0];

let parsedUsersListArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(book.Sheets[sheet_name]);
console.log(parsedUsersListArr.length);
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что именно я делаю не так. 
Или подскажите, каким образом можно спарсить файл в массив JSON объектов.

Comment: А как вы пытаетесь открыть файл без ноды? В браузере же? Тогда вам input type=file нужен и FileReader..

Comment: Да, в браузере. Спасибо за заданное направление.